# What's a robust strategy for displaying 3D map data for navigation?

Tags: coordinate-system, 3d, c++

3D map data, specifically the kind you see on GPS units, or more recently on smart phones, almost always features a 'HUD' like view, which I'm trying to implement in an application of mine. I have OpenStreetMaps data (offline) available to my application, where all the geometry is specified in latitude and longitude.

With 2D maps, there's a 'standard', where almost everyone uses N*N tiles of Mercator projected data. But with 3D data,

- I don't know what projection I should be using (I still have to map the latitude, longitude and altitude to x,y,z)
- I'm not too sure what's the best way to make data continually available in 'chunks' to a display engine as a user pans and zooms the map view

If it matters, I'm using C++ with the OpenSceneGraph library (which is basically a scene graph wrapper/toolkit for OpenGL). I'd appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of navigation you're talking about. I'll assume car navigation.

Since you're only showing a small slice of Earth (as opposed to Google Earth, which can show the whole Earth), you can simplify some things, for example:

- You can convert OSM's lat/lon coordinates into localized "flat Earth" coordinates (using the latitude to calculate the ratio to the longitude).
- Projection: the [perspective projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection), I guess. I'm sure you'll be using a 3D engine, so you get that in the box.
- Also take a look at [level of detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_detail) algorithms and data structures. If you really serious about your project, I recommend buying [Level of Detail for 3D Graphics](http://lodbook.com/) book
- There are several open source OSM 3D projects, so you can study their code and contact developers: http://www.osm-3d.org/map.htm, http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/3D_Development

Good luck!